# how to hard code WCF config?

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config

I try to create hard coded wcf service (no app.config) I tried the following

```
service = new CommService.TwService();

localHost = new ServiceHost(service);

ServiceMetadataBehavior behavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
localHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior);

localHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange),
     MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexNamedPipeBinding(),
     "net.pipe://localhost/service/mex/");

localHost.Open();
```

fails with :

> Service 'CommService.TwService' has zero application
>   (non-infrastructure)  endpoints.    This might be because no
>   configuration file was found for your   application,  or because no
>   service element matching the service name could be found in the 
>   configuration file, or because no endpoints were defined in the
>   service element.

Comment: You need to create a binding for your service and add that as an endpoint to the servicehost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have only added an endpoint for Mex, which will not expose the service itself. You need to add another binding explicitly for the service implementation, for example;

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
localHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(CommService.TwService), binding, "http://localhost/service");
```

Comment: var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
                localHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(CommService.ITwService), binding, "net.pipe://localhost/service/");

worked. thanks!